# How to embed a playlist from youtube without pause

Tags: iframe, video, youtube, embed, autoplay

I want to embed a playlist from youtube on a website. 
The problem is: after one video it goes to pause and a black screen. You must click to see the next video.
 How can I avoid the click and make the playlist autoplay to the next video. 
Note: I do not want the first video to start playing automatically. But once clicked, the whole playlist must play without pause.

Example with pause is over here: http://www.cliffdemandt.nl/youtube/

I hope you can help me out.

Regards,
Cliff

Comment: I'm also having this problem! Thanks for asking it. For me, this is happening on Chrome. Mozilla is working fine - it autoplays the next one without user interaction. I've never had this problem before - maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly fine for me(in Chrome). Although the playlist paused for a second after end of one video, it instantly auto played the next one. Try using the below link format in your player iframe.

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID&playlist=VIDEOID_1,VIDEOID_2"
```

You can generate similar playlist using [Youtube embed code generator](http://codegena.com/generator/Youtube-Embed-Code-Generator.html)